# Citrus-Framework change variable during scenario execution

Tags: java, cucumber, citrus-framework

I want to initialize some variables in order create a new item in my database, then in the same scenario change one variable, but keep the other variables the same and do an update. For example:

```
Update path: path/${resourceId}/${orderId}

@DEV @API
  Scenario: order not found in container
    Given variables
      | resourceId           | citrus:randomUUID()           |
      | orderId              | citrus:randomString(10,false) |
      | errorCode            | 404                           |
      | reasonPhrase         | NOT_FOUND                     | 

 When <ApiClient> sends message <containerPostRequest>
 And <ApiClient> should receive Json message <containerPostResponse>
 Given variable orderId is "newString"
 And <ApiClient> sends message <addOrderRequest>
 Then <ApiClient> should receive Json message <errorResponse>
```

I am attempting to throw an order not found exception, but using this method sets orderId to newString from the very beginning so the order is being created and located with newString.

Is this approach possible?

I can hard code scenarios and backgrounds to achieve my goal, but the method above I'm trying to use would reduce the amount of code I would need to write.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `Given variable ... is "..."` overwrites the variables in test case initialization. This is not what we need in your case. You need to use a test action that overwrites the variable as part of the test execution. You can do this with following custom step definition:

```
Then set variable orderId to "newString"
```

You need to add a step definition that implements this step.

```
public class SetVariableStep {

    @CitrusResource
    private TestDesigner designer;

    @Then("^set variable ([^\\s]+) to \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void setVariable(String name, String value) {
        designer.createVariable(name, value);
    }
}
```

The Citrus team should add this to the default step definition implementations.